# Facing issue while calling post method from angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am calling post web api method from angular but getting below error: 
"Failed to load : Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404"
I have enabled allow for cross origin request.

See below code:

```
 return this._http.post("http://localhost:64575/api/Rules", 
{
  currentPage: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
  sortColumn: 'id',
  sortDirection: 'asc'      
}, requestOptions)    
.map(res=>res.json());
```

Comment: Without any code you'll get no answer. Provide some meaningful part of your codebase and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you issue a Post request 2 calls are made to server

1. Call with "Options" request method
2. Actual post call

Now you need to handle "Options" call on your API implementation
Reference link: [Handling CORS Preflight in Asp.net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290317/handling-cors-preflight-in-asp-net-web-api)